# display / hide td of multiple table with jquery in one page

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have multiple table in one page and want add more / close td function in jquery, but i could not do it. i do not know where is the wrong, it didn't works clearly.

```
  <table class="table" ><tr>
        <td>    bla bla</td>
        <td>    bla bla</td>
        <td>    bla bla</td>
        <td>    bla bla</td>
    </tr>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btnods">+</button>
    </table>
    
    <table class="table" ><tr>
        <td>    bla bla</td>
        <td>    bla bla</td>
        <td>    bla bla</td>
        <td>    bla bla</td>
    </tr>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btnods">+</button>
    </table>
  
    
    <script>
    $(".btnods").on('click',function() {
      if ($(this).text() == "+") {
        $(this).siblings('.table').find("td").slice(0,20).show();
        $(this).html("Kapat");
      } else {
    
        $(this).siblings('.table').find("td").hide().slice(0, 80).show();
        $(this).html("+");
      }
    });
    
    </script>
```

thank you for your help.

Comment: You want to be able to add more tables by clicking the plus button?

Comment: no, not tables, i just want display / hide function for td of table or cell of table, how u call

Comment: First you button is not a sibling of the table, but a child. Second button is not a valid child of table

Comment: then how i can fix this?

Comment: On the click of +, you want to add more rows in the table? Is that the question?

Comment: not row or table, i just want the TD OF TABLE, hide / show function in jquery

Comment: @codernthnth You are also using `show()` both places, so you will never see any changes. I suggest that you slow down a bit and check your code.

Comment: i tested like u said, but still problem

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
$(".btnods").on('click', function() {
  if ($(this).text() == "+") {
    $(this).next('.table').find("td").slice(0, 20).hide();
    $(this).html("Kapat");
  } else {
    $(this).next('.table').find("td").hide().slice(0, 80).show();
    $(this).html("+");
  }
});
```

Note as i stated, then button is not a valid child of a table. Second, you need to use `.next()` in your case. Third, you used `.show()` both places.

**Demo**

```js
$(".btnods").on('click', function() {
  if ($(this).text() == "+") {
    $(this).next('.table').find("td").slice(0, 20).hide();
    $(this).html("Kapat");
  } else {
    $(this).next('.table').find("td").hide().slice(0, 80).show();
    $(this).html("+");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btnods">+</button>
<table class="table">
  <tr>
    <td> bla bla</td>
    <td> bla bla</td>
    <td> bla bla</td>
    <td> bla bla</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btnods">+</button>
<table class="table">
  <tr>
    <td> bla bla</td>
    <td> bla bla</td>
    <td> bla bla</td>
    <td> bla bla</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: unfortunely, it didn't work

Comment: Did you move the button out of your table? did you made sure to use `.hide()`